# Action Bar missing in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation

I have been working on Navigation Drawer. But my getActionBar() is getting caught in NullPointerException. On surrounding it with try and catch, the ActionBar becomes invisible. Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Please post your Activity and your styles.xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` above your `R.layout`line. Hope this helps.